# angular js alert by click donot work

Tags: angularjs

i am new to AngularJS so please forgive me this dump question. 
i have error

```
Cannot set property 'test' of undefined
```

angularjs

```
var App = angular.module('StartModule', []);
 App.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', [
function($scope) {

    $scope.test = function() {
        alert("12312");
    }
}
]);
```

html

```
<body ng-app="StartModule">
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<div ng-click="test()">11111</div>
</div>
<body>
```

Comment: Next time please thoroughly check your code against the documentation for basic mistakes like this before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You just miss `$scope` to controller's second argument:

```
var App = angular.module('StartModule', []);
App.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', [ $scope, function($scope) {
    $scope.test = function() {
        alert("12312");
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `$scope` dependency, you need to inject it in your controller :

```
App.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope'
    function($scope) {
```

That's why the `$scope` variable is undefined, you're not actually injecting any dependency in it.

This uses the Inline Array Annotation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di